# I can't get Steam to run on Ubuntu 20.04 - "Fatal error - Steam needs to be online" and "Unmet packages"

Tags: 20.04, steam

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 20.04 and I simply can't get Steam working. I downloaded the .deb file from their website and went through the download process with no problems at all - but when I launch the steam client installer it says "fatal error - steam needs to be online to update". I tried downloading it from the Ubuntu Software but it simply says it can't download because of "unmet dependencies." There are recent comments there complaining about the same issue.

I looked through tutorials online but most of them were outdated and didn't work at all or were for other distros such as arch.  Please if you ran through this problem help me me solve it, thanks.

Comment: Edit your question to show us the actual complete output. Summaries lack the vital detail we need to help you. It's not clear if you have a network problem (not online), or if you broke your system (unmet dependencies), or both, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue but I found Battenborn's comment here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=263871

In your terminal you have to run:
`ping media.steampowered.com`
Copy the IP address in brackets. For me it was 62.24.203.41
Then run:
`sudo nano /etc/hosts`
and add the following to that file:

`IP    client-download.steampowered.com`

so for me it was:

`62.24.203.41    client-download.steampowered.com`

If you don't know how to use nano. Press Ctrl + O then enter to save and Ctrl + X to exit :)